# How can I add symbols to a cell using closedxml?

Tags: c#, excel-2007, closedxml

I am inserting data into a dummy excel. I need to append symbols before texts into some cell.
Please let me know how can i achieve this using ClosedXML.

[image: I want this through closedxml]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ClosedXML, you can set this value with this code:

```
ws.Cell(1, 1).Value = "❶ Symbol";
```

To enter the ❶, you can use the Windows program `Character Map` to select and copy the appropriate character.

Comment: Hi Francois Botha, I am asking to achieve this in C# using ClosedXML. So please show any example in closedxml if you know.

Comment: Thanks a lot Francois Botha. It is working like a charm. I tried this before but was not able to copy these characters from excel sheets insert symbol area. But Windows program for Character Map is just a nice tool. Thanks once again.

Comment: Hello Francois, I have another query. It would be a great help to me if can answer this as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39572289/how-to-download-existing-excel-file-in-c-sharp-using-closedxml?noredirect=1#comment66454214_39572289